# "FltUser.h - no such file or directory" when compiling with v140_xp toolset on visual studio 2015

Tags: compilation

I wrote a minifilter driver and I want it to run on windows xp.
Therefore I compiled it with platform toolset v140_xp and I noticed the file FltUser.h doesnt exists on Windows SDK version 7.1.

Someone know how I can use FltUser.h and still use SDK 7.1 (so it will support Windows XP SP2)

Thanks.